# C statement between function declaration and curly brace

Tags: c, curly-braces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is useful about this C syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630631/what-is-useful-about-this-c-syntax)
>   [C variable declarations after function heading in definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633776/c-variable-declarations-after-function-heading-in-definition)
>   [What weird C syntax is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380599/what-weird-c-syntax-is-this)

I'm trying to understand some code and it has something like the following:

```
int getr(fget)
FILE *fget;
{
   /* More declarations and statements here */
   return (1);
}
```

Is there any difference between the above and:

```
int getr(fget)
{
   FILE *fget;
   /* More declarations and statements here */
   return (1);
}
```

If so, how do they differ?

Comment: @Paul R. You are correct, this is a duplicate of that question.  Is is possible to edit the title of that question to be more descriptive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both functions are declared in the old-style (non-prototype) form. Old-style function declarations are obsolescent in the current C standard and their use is strongly discouraged by the C Standard.

In the second form there is no mention of the `fget` parameter type which is assumed to be an `int`. Then another object `fget` of type `FILE *` is declared and it shadows the parameter variable with the same name.

With `gcc` the `-Wshadow` warning option would get you a warning in your second example because of the shadowing of the parameter:

```
   -Wshadow
       Warn whenever a local variable shadows another local variable, 
       parameter or global variable or whenever a built-in function is shadowed.
```

Comment: So I assume the "encouraged" way to do it would be:  `int getr(FILE* fget) { ...}` ? (preferably with a prototype at the top of the file)

Comment: @mgilson: yes, you should define the function as: `int getr(FILE* fget) { ...}`. This is a function definition in the prototype syntax. Note that this function definition also serves as a prototype for later in the source code.

Answer (score 7):

The first one is the **[K & R style of function definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style)**, it is an obsolescent feature<sup>Ref 1</sup>.

The second is popularly known as **Implicit int** feature prior to c99 standard.
Prior to c99 If a function returned no explicit type or didn't specify a type in declaration, then the type was assumed to be a `int`.

Both of the methods have been deprecated and find a mention in the c99 Standard.

References:
**C99 Standard:  Foreword Para 7:**

> Major changes in the second edition included:
>   — remove implicit int
>   — remove implicit function declaration

**<sup>Ref 1</sup>**
**6.11.7 Function definitions**

> The use of function definitions with separate parameter identifier and declaration lists
>   (not prototype-format parameter type and identifier declarators) is an obsolescent feature.